# Different Time Format in ruby 1.9.2 from ruby 1.8.7 causing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, ruby-1.9.2

I am upgrading the ruby version from ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 1.9.2 in my exiting Ruby on rails application which has extensive use of Time related calculations. But after switching to ruby 1.9.2 -p290 its not working. I guess the issue is with

```
$ rvm use 1.8.7

ruby-1.8.7-p334 :001 > Time.now
=> Thu May 12 12:42:35 +0200 2011 

$ rvm use 1.9.2

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > Time.now
=> 2011-05-12 12:42:44 +0200
```

Can some please tell me how to solve this kind of issue or How can change or override default ruby 1.9.2 format back to the old one or how to solve this time related changes in the newer version of ruby.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
Time.now.asctime
```

in 1.9

EDIT 1:

well, depends on how you're going to use it. This should probably work for you:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Time
irb(main):002:1> class << self
irb(main):003:2>   alias :orig_now :now
irb(main):004:2>
irb(main):005:2*   def now
irb(main):006:3>     orig_now.asctime
irb(main):007:3>   end
irb(main):008:2> end
irb(main):009:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> Time.now
=> "Thu Jul 28 12:29:08 2011"  # STRING
irb(main):011:0>
```

EDIT 2:

Ok, I got your question somewhat wrong. The above patch will cause Time.now to return the string (not the Time object).

If you just want to see Time object to be represented different you could apply this:

```
irb(main):011:0> class Time
irb(main):012:1>
irb(main):013:1* def inspect
irb(main):014:2>   self.asctime
irb(main):015:2> end
irb(main):016:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):017:0> Time.now
=> Thu Jul 28 13:41:16 2011   # TIME
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but i don't want to change the calculations at every position , is there a way to overwrite the time format by doing something is initializer like overrite the default format or change default format.

Comment: So should i create an initializer file with the code , you have mentioned and there is no need to change at every position. right?

Comment: Okay , Thanks Vlad Khomich for your time , let me try to create an initializer file and then will put the class which you have given and then try to run the code.

Comment: Time.now is now showing me in right format but it is showing me this error , undefined method `strftime' for "Thu Jul 28 09:59:42 2011":String , what i have done is Time.now.to_time.strftime("%m") but gives me error on server startup .. .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:83:in `log': undefined method `strftime' for "Thu Jul 28 10:06:49 2011":String (NoMethodError)

Comment: (Object doesn't support #inspect) this is what it is showing me , when i am trying that in my rails console